# How to avoid Cassandra read failure, due to large tombstone scans?

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

I use Apache Spark to read data from Cassandra, which under the hood does, token range based scan. But, recently I see a lot of failure during data read from my Cassandra table.

Read fails with below cause:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException: Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)    
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:85)  
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadFailureException.copy(ReadFailureException.java:27)  
at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)   
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)  
at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
```

When I checked the systemlogs I found out below issue:

```
ERROR [ReadStage-1] 2020-04-09 10:25:59,701 StorageProxy.java:1896 - Scanned over 100001 tombstones during query 'SELECT * FROM my_keyspace.my_table WHERE token(id) > -5868586221781016365 AND token(id) <= -5347313590141106513 LIMIT 5000' (last scanned row partion key was (my_key_1)); query aborted
```

The error log is straight forward, the reads are failing due to tombstone scans.

What I don't get is, I was running the same Spark job for over a year and never faced this problem. But, that's secondary. First I would like to know how can I fix this?

The tombstones could be created for the column values that are not passed, as I use Cassandra Insert Json feature to insert doc. Confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61768228/does-cassandra-insert-json-creates-tombstones/61768812#61768812), that this approach will create the tombstones.

How do I fix this? Creating multiple insert queries based on non-null values is a complicated option.

Even inserting dummy value is impractical in my opinion. All the clients that read data from these tables need to make the change.

I personally feel Cassandra should never create Tombstone for a column if the column doesn't exist in JSON.

What are the other options to solve this?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for these failures. What queries are you trying to run? Are you trying to fetch all records from the table without key?

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but the easiest way to mitigate tombstones in Cassandra, is to build data models that don't create them in the first place.  I wish more people understood that.

Comment: @Aaron Agree, this doesn't help :) It is not always possible to avoid tombstones. But there are ways to solve or minimize the problem, I had couple of options but those aren't feasible at this moment. So, asked the questions. 
I know there are options to avoid column-based tombstones, by storing my data in `Map` or a `text` type and store JSON. 
We need the schema. Feel free to suggest, If you have thought of any other data model to avoid tombstones? 
Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

1. Don't insert data as JSON, but instead parse JSON in application, and insert data, using `unset` instead of missing values (done by default, [look to docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/statements/prepared/#parameters-and-binding)) - you can simplify your work by mapping JSON into POJO, and using Object Mapper that also supports replacement of nulls with `unset`.  This is best approach, as tombstones will affect all applications, and Cassandra itself. But real solution will depend on your use case - are you inserting only new data, or you're updating existing as well? In the later case, you'll need to make sure that you overwrite previous data
2. Decrease the page size in Spark application to read less rows in one page.  This is regulated by `spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows` parameter, [described in docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.0/doc/reference.md#read-tuning-parameters).  If you're using DSE with DSE Analytics, you may need to disable continuous paging

Comment: Thank Alex. At the moment we are only inserting, it could be a new record or a record with a same key that exists in our table. Insert and Upsert

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for. I will go with the second option and see how it performs. In the long run, we definitely need to change our code to adopt first option.

Comment: for upsert, there could be a problem with following - for example, first insert was with fields 1 & 3, and 2nd - with fields 1,4,5 - if you don't put `null` for field 3, you'll end with fields 1,3,4,5, and this is not you always want. Tombstones in insertion of JSON are specifically to prevent such cases

Comment: As you mentioned about unest. I was checking the same feature in Insert Json. 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html
I am assuming it has the same effect. 
From the doc `Use the DEFAULT UNSET option to only overwrite values found in the JSON string`

Comment: We are using upserts quite a bit, as in our NRT flow, many docs come in that have the same partition key. So, it will not be possible to avoid tombstones.
I am going with a lower fetch size. See how it goes.

Comment: Yes, default unset may help you (I always forget about it, as I rarely see JSON in the wild), but will be the same problem with merging with previous data...